# Using numpy array as test cases for looped Monte Carlo

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I have what I'm sure is a very simple problem to solve but I can't seem to get it right and have not been able to search for an answer, likely because I am using the wrong vocabulary, etc.

My goal is to have an array, called array_1, which has different 'test cases'. For each of the elements in that array, I want to run a Monte Carlo, with the current element being the input to a function. I would like to get the mean of all of the results (num_samples) and store that into another array, which will be an array of the 'means' to be easily visualized. Hard coding for each of the conditions is easy but I am looking for a more automated method. Any help would be appreciated. What I'm currently working with is below:

```
import numpy as np

num_samples = 5
array_1 = ([1,2,3])
array_2 = np.zeros(num_samples)
array_3 = ([])



def func_add(a, b):
    return a + b + 2
#def func_append(c):

for j in array_1:
    for i in range(num_samples):
        r = np.random.randint(1,2)
        array_2[i] = func_add( j, r)
        c = np.mean(array_2) #this value I want to put in a new array to have an 'array of means'
        #print(b)
    array_3 = np.append(array_3, c)

print(array_2)
print(np.mean(array_2))
print(c)
print(array_3)
```

Which returns:

```
[6. 6. 6. 6. 6.]
6.0
6.0
[4. 5. 6.]
```

EDIT 2: The results for array_3 seem to make sense but now I'm curious as to why array_2 only contains 6's. In the first case of the loops, j = 1 and r = 1, so the function should return 4 and place that in index 1 for array_2, or do they all get overwritten by the last case of the for loop, which also would make sense I think.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I think the problem is that maybe that I'm pulling the value from array_1 but I want to put the mean from the processing into the first index of some array(meaning I might have to create a third array to hold those values?)

Answer (score 0):

Outside the loop, you can instantiate `c` as an empty numpy array. Inside the for loop, you append the mean to the end of c:

```py
 np.append(c, np.mean(array_2))
```

Thus, the array `c` grows with each iteration until it contains all results.